# Change node direction

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics

I'm developing a game almost like breakout, and considering the position the ball hits the paddle it should change it's direction.

[image]

Here is a masterpiece to explain which functionality I'm trying to reach. I'm already able to get the position where the ball hits the paddle. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why aren't you letting the physics engine do the work?

Comment: I want to give the user a better control on where to aim the ball, just like it happens in breakout games.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determine the center points of your ball and paddle at the moment of contact using didBeginContact.

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);

    if (collision == (CategoryBall | CategoryPaddle))
    {
        if((contact.bodyA.node.position.x > contact.bodyB.node.position.x) && (contact.bodyA.node.position.x <= contact.bodyB.node.position.x+10))
        {
            // ball's center is a little to the right of paddle's center
        }

        if(contact.bodyA.node.position.x > contact.bodyB.node.position.x+10)
        {
            // ball's center is more to the right of paddle's center
        }

        if((contact.bodyA.node.position.x < contact.bodyB.node.position.x) && (contact.bodyA.node.position.x >= contact.bodyB.node.position.x-10))
        {
            // ball's center is a little to the left of paddle's center
        }

        if(contact.bodyA.node.position.x < contact.bodyB.node.position.x-10)
        {
            // ball's center is more to the left of paddle's center
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was already able to determine the center point of the paddle and ball, but I don't know how to change the ball direction. Is there a property, or something like this?

Comment: @LucasDomene - You need to use the velocity property of your ball.